# Crystal Report "The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached"

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using following code to print a crystal report. It prints frequently and after 75th print, I get the following error. "The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached". I'm disposing the report every time but I forgot to close it before disposing. is it the issue?. if not what is the correct method of doing this?. I'm using SAP crystal report for .Net framework free edition. (I do not use a crystal report viewer and directly print it)

```
    Dim crepBill As New repBill
    crepBill.Refresh()
    crepBill.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
    crepBill.Dispose()
```

Comment: Here are some google results that seem to have solved this type of issue: [SAP](https://answers.sap.com/questions/4797136/index.html) [ASP .Net](https://forums.asp.net/p/1322885/2640173.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. "crepBill.Close()" resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

closing the report solves the issue

```
crepBill.Close()
```

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13203577/the-maximum-report-processing-jobs-limit-configure-2.html?childToView=13202957

Answer (score 0):

My code (VB.Net)

```
  Public Sub CryPrintreport(ByVal ds As DataTable, ByVal crpt As ReportDocument)

        Dim FrmChild As New clsRptForm
        Dim crytrpt As New CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
        
        Try
            crpt.SetDataSource(ds)
            crytrpt.ReportSource = crpt

            With FrmChild
                .AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)
                .ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 10, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 10)
                .Controls.Add(crytrpt)
                .WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
                .ResumeLayout(False)

                crytrpt.ActiveViewIndex = -1
                crytrpt.Anchor = 15              
                crytrpt.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
                crytrpt.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
                crytrpt.Width = FrmChild.Width - 20
                crytrpt.Height = FrmChild.Height - 30
            End With
            
            FrmChild.Show()

           
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Finally

        End Try

    End Sub

'=========new class form ===================

Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Public Class clsRptForm

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private Sub Form_closed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        Dim ctrl As Object
        Try
            For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 
                Select Case LCase$(TypeName(ctrl))
                    Case "crystalreportviewer"
                        If Not (CType(ctrl.ReportSource, ReportDocument) Is Nothing) Then
                            CType(ctrl.ReportSource, ReportDocument).Close()
                            CType(ctrl.ReportSource, ReportDocument).Dispose()
                        End If

                End Select
            Next ctrl
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```